# Open CV capture read() does not read specific video frames fps 59.9

Tags: opencv

I have code to read video frames from a file:

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
fps = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
frame_count = int(starting_time * fps)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_count)

while video_capture.isOpened():

    success, np_image = video_capture.read()

    if success is False:
        break

    else ......
```

files are mp4 and fps is 59.9.

However, it can not read successfully some frames - from 53-59. That is video_capture.read() returns False.

Converting it to AVI format resolves that issue. However, I am trying to find if there is a way to return why it could not read the frame and returns False.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This has been a problem in highly compressed videos (p, b frame enabled). This issue seems to be fixed [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4890). So updating your OpenCV version might help. This issue won't occur in the least compressible videos (I frame) like avi.